# "The read session is not available for the input session token." exception

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm having a problem on Azure DocumentDB with a single partion collection.
Whenever I try to programmatically insert or query any document, I get an exception with the message saying

> "The read session is not available for the input session token."

As this collection was newly created, I thought this was a generic error and I tried to recreate the collection on another database, but then when trying to create the collection I can't submit the deploy because I get asked of the partition key.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkvlG.png)

Standing on what the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-partition-data) says,

> "You do not have to specify a partition key for these collections."

Can someone help? Am I doing something wrong?
The region is West Europe (in case it helps)

Comment: Can you add the `client` creation/initialization code? Are you caching it or recreating it everytime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the error you're getting about the input session token, can you add your code here?

For the issue in the portal where you're trying to create a collection, do the following:

- In the partition key box, enter space and then press delete, you should get a green check mark in the box.

This will be fixed in the portal shortly.

Comment: IDocumentQuery<T> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(
                UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId))
                .Where(predicate)
                .AsDocumentQuery();

            List<T> results = new List<T>();
            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>());
            }

            return results;

Comment: "The read session is not available for the input session token" error was fixed in .NET SDK 1.11.4. Please upgrade to the latest SDK and let us know if you still see this error. If yes, please email askdocdb at Microsoft DOT com with the ActivityId of the failed request.

Answer (score 0):

I assume from your code that you are trying to create a generic **pagination** logic. From my experience with DocDB, pagination needs to be achieved by using the [Continuation Token](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.documents.client.feedoptions.requestcontinuation.aspx).

I generally have [an extension](https://github.com/ealsur/auth0documentdb/blob/master/Extensions/DocumentDbLinqExtensions.cs#L36) that obtains said token and then I use it on subsequent requests like so:

```
/// <summary>
/// Paged results with continuation token
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public class PagedResults<T>
{
    public PagedResults()
    {
        Results = new List<T>();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Continuation Token for DocumentDB
    /// </summary>
    public string ContinuationToken { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Results
    /// </summary>
    public List<T> Results { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Creates a pagination wrapper with Continuation Token support
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
/// <param name="source"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static async Task<PagedResults<T>> ToPagedResults<T>(this IQueryable<T> source)
{
    var documentQuery = source.AsDocumentQuery();
    var results = new PagedResults<T>();

    try
    {
        var queryResult = await documentQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<T>();
        if (!queryResult.Any())
        {
            return results;
        }
        results.ContinuationToken = queryResult.ResponseContinuation;
        results.Results.AddRange(queryResult);
    }
    catch
    {
        //documentQuery.ExecuteNextAsync might throw an Exception if there are no results
        return results;
    }

    return results;
}
```

You can use this helper in your code along with the [FeedOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.documents.client.feedoptions.aspx):

```
var feedOptions = new FeedOptions() { MaxItemCount = sizeOfPage };
var collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId);
PagedResults<T> results = await client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(collectionUri,feedOptions).Where(predicate).ToPagedResults();
//You can check of the ContinuationToken and use it on another query
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(results.ContinuationToken)){
    feedOptions.RequestContinuation = results.ContinuationToken;
    PagedResults<T> moreResults = await client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>( collectionUri,feedOptions ).Where(predicate).ToPagedResults();
}
```

Also, I maintain a repo on Github that contains [helpers and providers](https://github.com/ealsur/auth0documentdb/blob/master/Services/DocumentDbProvider.cs) for DocDB that you are free to use if you want, most are based on the [Performance guidelines article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-performance-tips) and personal experience.

Another word of advice, try to update your SDK to the latest version, either the [.Net Full framework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB) or the [.Net Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core) version (depending on your project).

Comment: This method is one of the many failing from today's "accident". The purpose of that method is to get only 5 items(sorry I wasn't clear, but that's the one that was throwing the exception in the first place as it loads results for the home page), and the same method has an overload that uses the FeedOptions and the continuation token (i.e.  var options = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = pageCount, EnableScanInQuery = true } )
Thank you for your help though, I had a look at the helper and the git repo and found the whole thing interesting!